# Suppress ggpairs messages when generating plot

Tags: r, ggally

ggpairs prints out a progress bar and estimated remaining time while generating plots, which is nice when used interactively since some of the computations can take a few seconds. But when making documents, like R notebooks, these printed messages end up in the report. [ggpairs had a boolean `verbose` option, but it's depricated now](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GGally/versions/1.2.0/topics/ggpairs). Is there an alternative? I can't seem to find one.

To see the messages try:

`library(GGally)
ggpairs(mtcars, columns = c("mpg", "cyl", "hp", "disp", "am", "qsec"))`

In a document it ends up including:

> plot: [1,1] [==-------------------------------------------]  4% est: 0s
>
> plot: [1,2] [====-----------------------------------------]  8% est: 6s
>
> plot: [1,3] [=====----------------------------------------] 12% est: 5s
>
> plot: [1,4] [=======--------------------------------------] 16% est: 5s

etc

Comment: can you use `message = FALSE` in the chunk options

Comment: I tried `message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE` but they still show up.

Comment: I also tried wrapping the code in `suppressMessages()`. Didn't work either.

Comment: Try with `progress = FALSE`. It seems to be called by [`ggmatrix_gtable`](https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/blob/ab0311e3c7cc959bec7f3b468094ed976af5c37c/R/ggmatrix_gtable.R), which takes a boolean `progress` argument. I'm not sure (haven't tested) if `progress = F` will be passed along deep enough.

Comment: @Gregor `progress = FALSE` in chunk option didn't work either.

Comment: Not in the chunk option, in the `ggpairs` call. But no, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `progress = FALSE` argument will work when printing the `ggpairs` plot.

```
ggp = ggpairs(mtcars, columns = c("mpg", "cyl", "hp", "disp"))
print(ggp, progress = F)  # no progress bar
print(ggp)  # progress bar
```

It may also depend *how* you `knit`. The function that call the progress bar is `ggmatrix_gtable`, with the default value as

```
 progress = interactive() && (pm$ncol * pm$nrow) > 15
```

Thus no progress bar is printed by default in a non-interactive session.

Comment: Thank, this works! Re: knitting, I'm using the recently added `Preview Notebook` button in RStudio.

Answer (score 7):

'progress' parameter in print function will soon be deprecated.

It can be passed to ggpairs itself:

```r
library(GGally)
ggpairs(mtcars, 
        columns = c("mpg", "cyl", "hp", "disp", "am", "qsec"),
        progress = FALSE)
```

RStudio screenshot for ggpairs without progress:

[image: ggpairs output without progress]

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with `dplyr` syntax, maybe the following piping is the most elegant one which do not require saving intermediate variable

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggpairs(columns = c("mpg", "cyl", "hp", "disp", "am", "qsec")) %>%
  print(progress = F)
```